# CTE Error near Update

Tags: sql, sap-iq

Hi I am using Sybase 16.

Whenever I run this CTE, it gives me an error: 'Syntax error near Update'...

`With Remove_Dup_Nov13(pk_viewing_prog_instance_fact, Rank_instance)
As
(Select pk_viewing_prog_instance_fact,
        row_number()over(partition by dk_programme_instance_dim, subscriber_id, account_number,
        instance_start_date_time_utc, instance_end_date_time_utc, instance_duration
                      order by dk_programme_instance_dim, subscriber_id, account_number,
                      instance_start_date_time_utc, instance_end_date_time_utc, instance_duration) rank_instance
                      From Viewing_Cribs_Nov13
                      )
Update Viewing_Cribs_Nov13
Set a.Rank_instance = b.Rank_instance
from Viewing_Cribs_Nov13 as a
inner join
Remove_Dup_Nov13 as b
on a.pk_viewing_prog_instance_fact = b.pk_viewing_prog_instance_fact;`

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You have the column you are updating set with an alias and not the table you're updating:

```
Update Viewing_Cribs_Nov13
Set Rank_instance = b.Rank_instance
from Viewing_Cribs_Nov13 as a
inner join
Remove_Dup_Nov13 as b
on a.pk_viewing_prog_instance_fact = b.pk_viewing_prog_instance_fact;
```

OR

```
Update a
Set Rank_instance = b.Rank_instance
from Viewing_Cribs_Nov13 as a
inner join
Remove_Dup_Nov13 as b
on a.pk_viewing_prog_instance_fact = b.pk_viewing_prog_instance_fact;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Sir.But it still gives me the same error. I can put the CTE query into a temporary table and then Run and Update the table separately. My question is more in lines with why do I get an error in such a simple CTE. Is it because of Sybase? Or is it because no window functions/ rank functions are allowed in a subquery within Sybase.

Comment: It's likely.  I know Sybase supports CTEs, but I'm not sure if the update works the same as in SQL Server.  If I find the details, I'll post.